# Why do I have many more jobs `started` than running or suspended?

Tags: lsf

According to the `bqueues` manual page:

```
STARTED
         Number of job slots used by running or
         suspended jobs owned by users or user groups in
         the queue.
```

According to `bqueues`, I have 369 jobs started:

```
$ bqueues -r lotus | egrep '(STARTED|gholl)'
 USER/GROUP   SHARES  PRIORITY  STARTED  RESERVED  CPU_TIME  RUN_TIME   ADJUST
gholl          10       0.006    369        0   2334366.5   723589       0.000
```

But when I run `bjobs`, it only shows 24 jobs that are running or suspended:

```
$ bjobs | egrep '(RUN|SUSP)' | wc -l
24
```

What explains the discrepancy between 24 jobs running and 369 jobs started?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number in `STARTED` refers to the number of slots.  One job may take up more than one slot if it uses multiple threads.  For example, if a job is submitted using `bsubs` with the flag `-n 16`, then each job will use 16 jobs.  23×16+1=368, so in the example above, user `gholl` has 23 jobs using 16 slots and 1 job using 1 slot.